# Make a field state change depending on the moderation state field

Tags: 8

I am trying to use the states to change another field depending on the moderation state, I tried this, but didn't catch it.

```
$form['schedule_publish_date'] ['#states'] =  array(
 'invisible' => array(
  ':input[name="moderation_state"]' => array('value' =>"published"),
 ),
```

I'm not sure what the correct field name of the moderation state is, this is the source code `<div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-select form-type-select js-form-item-moderation-state-0 form-item-moderation-state-0">
      <label for="edit-moderation-state-0">Moderation state</label>
        <select data-drupal-selector="edit-moderation-state-0" aria-describedby="edit-moderation-state-0--description" id="edit-moderation-state-0" name="moderation_state[0]" class="form-select"><option value="draft" selected="selected">Draft</option><option value="needs_review">Needs Review</option><option value="approved_to_be_published">Approved to be published</option><option value="published">Published</option></select>
            <div id="edit-moderation-state-0--description" class="description">
      The moderation state of this piece of content.
    </div>
  </div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal API: [function drupal_process_states](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/8.3.x)

Example A where the source fieldtype is a textfield

```
$form['moderation_state'] = [
  '#type'  => 'textfield',
  '#title' => ('Some title'),
];

$form['schedule_publish_date'] = [
  '#type'   => 'textfield',
  '#title'  => ('Invisible if ...'),
  '#states' => ['invisible' => [':input[name="moderation_state"]' => ['value' => "published"],],],
];
```

Example B where the source fieldtype is a select-field

```
$form['moderation_state'] = array(
  '#type'          => 'select',
  '#title'         => t('Some title'),
  '#options'       => array('unpublished'=>'unpublished', 'published'=>'published'),
  '#default_value' => 0,
);

$form['schedule_publish_date'] = [
  '#type'   => 'textfield',
  '#title'  => ('Invisible if ...'),
  '#states' => ['invisible' => [':input[name="moderation_state"]' => ['value' => "published"],],],
];
```

Comment: thanks but the moderation state comes from the work flow module, so the code for it is different , I can't really tell what the input name for it is.

Comment: Should be "moderation_state[0]"

Comment: $form['schedule_publish_date'] = [
      '#type'   => 'textfield',
      '#title'  => ('Invisible if ...'),
      '#states' => ['invisible' => [':input[name="moderation_state[0]"]' => ['value' => "published"],],],
    ];